# Downloading pdf from S3 via Lambda and API Gateway works on POSTMAN but failed in NodeJs Axios with Chrome error - Failed - Network error

Tags: node.js, pdf, lambda, axios, aws-api-gateway

[I can download a pdf from S3 via Lambda and API Gateway successfully.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cl9s6.jpg)

However, I used suggested NodeJs - Axios. It failed with "Failed - Network error".

```
  const downloadSearchResult = async (params) => {
    console.log("download")
    const link = document.createElement("a");
    var axios = require('axios');

    var config = {
      method: 'get',
      url: `https://xxxxxxx.amazonaws.com/v1/xxx?file=${params.row.Filename}`,
      headers: { 
      }
    };
    
    axios(config)
    .then(function (response) {
      link.href = `data:application/pdf;base64,` + response.data;
      link.download = params.row.Filename;
      link.click();
      console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

[Chrome showed the JSON.stringify(response.data) but the file won't save.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKe57.jpg)

[Chrome reported Failed - Network error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m583W.jpg)